# Links inside a tabindex-ed and focus-ed container don't work

Tags: css, focus, tabindex

Suppose we have a HTML simple hamburger navigation area, something like this

```
<!-- the navigation container  -->
<nav class="hamburger" tabindex="0">
    <!-- a svg icon -->
    <img src="img/menu2.svg">
    <!-- the links container, hidden at startup and showed on :focus on .hamburger container -->
    <div class="items">
        <a href="home.html">home</a>
        <a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a>
        <a href="contacts.html">contacts</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Now, using tabindex and CSS :focus pseudo-class on the .hamburger container, I'm able to open the menu on click; every click on a link or outside the nav area closes the menu as expected.

```
.hamburger {
    background-color: #789;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.hamburger img {
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 50px;
}

.hamburger .items {
    display: none;
}

.hamburger:focus .items {
    display: block;
}

.hamburger a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.hamburger a:hover {
    background-color: #345;
}
```

The only problem is that links (and buttons) do not work anymore: clicking on a link simply closes the menu without following the href.

I know I could use a :checked pseudo-class on a checkbox/label, but I'd like to know if someone is aware of a reason for this behaviour and hopefully has a solution to make links active again on a :focus-ed container like this.

Thanks a lot for every hint.

Answer (score 0):

After some more attempts, I'm now able to answer my own question.

Everything works as expected simply substituting the pseudoclass `:focus` with `:focus-within` that addresses the container of some elements getting focus-ed.

So substitutingin the CSS

```
.hamburger:focus .items {
    display: block;
}
```

with

```
.hamburger:focus-within .items {
    display: block;
}
```

solved the problem for me.